# Connect/Express per request middleware is failing somewhere

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I'm trying to do a very simple Basic Auth middleware for Express on Node.js as demonstrated here: http://node-js.ru/3-writing-express-middleware

I have my middleware function:

```
var basicAuth = function(request, response, next) {
    if (request.headers.authorization && request.headers.authorization.search('Basic ') === 0) {
        // Get the username and password
        var requestHeader = new Buffer(
                request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1], 'base64').toString();
        requestHeader = requestHeader.split(":");

        var username = requestHeader[0];
        var password = requestHeader[1];

        // This is an async that queries the database for the correct credentials
        authenticateUser(username, password, function(authenticated) {
            if (authenticated) {
                next();
            } else {
                response.send('Authentication required', 401);
            }
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Authentication required', 401);
    }
};
```

And I have my route:

```
app.get('/user/', basicAuth, function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end('Okay');
});
```

If I try to curl this request I get:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost/user/ --user user:password
Cannot GET /user/
```

This works totally cool when I add the middleware while calling createServer(), but when I do it per request like I am in this route, it just dies quietly server-side.  Unfortunately, since not all requests require authentication, I can't make this a global middleware.

I've tried flipping off Express and just using Connect and I get the same result, so I assume it's something in there.  Has anybody experienced this before?

Edit: I should also mention that I've logged the relevant code exhaustively and next is being called, but it just appears to go nowhere.

Edit 2: For the record, an "empty" middleware also fails silently:

```
var func = function(request, response, next) {
    next();
};

app.get('/user', func, function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end('Okay');
});
```

This also has the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`function(request, response, callback) {`

vs

`next();`

Your supposed to either change `callback` to `next` or vica versa.

Comment: Ahh, yes thanks for pointing that out.  Unfortunately it's just a result of tired eyes and copying and pasting messy code ;)  I edited the post, but the issue was happening with next being passed correctly.

Comment: your sure `authenticateUser` is not broken right? The 3rd `callback` argument does get called right?/

Comment: Positive, I've got a console.log right before the call to next() in basicAuth, as well as one in success/fail cases in authenticateUser.  It's definitely returning, and doing something with next.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link.

[Express middleware: Basic HTTP Authentication](http://node-js.ru/3-writing-express-middleware)

The author seems to be doing the same thing as you did, except he has a return after the next().